# This class inherits from a class marked as @immutable, and therefore should be immutable (all instance fields must be final)

Tags: visual-studio, flutter

Getting the below issue, and not able to solve it, Can anyone help me in solving this.

> This class inherits from a class marked as @immutable, and therefore should be immutable (all instance fields must be final). dart(must_be_immutable)

[image: Click the image here]

Thanks.

Comment: What prevents you from doing what the error suggests (changing `var` to `final`)?

Comment: What is the question here? Do you understand what the error message means? Is your question how to make your own class immutable?

Comment: The error suggests all the instance fields must be final @GünterZöchbauer

Comment: Yes it does. You create a StatelessWidget and add a variable state. That's somewhat contradicting ;-)

Answer (score 78):

This issue occurs when all the class variables are not declared as final. You can either make them final or for ignoring this warning you can add the following comment above the class declaration:

```
//ignore: must_be_immutable
```

Comment: What's the consequence of creating mutable variables in a StatelessWidget? Will it just be a loss of efficiency or something worse?

Comment: but when using bloc pattern things are not just normal, we have builder that return different widget based on state. So immutable is just a warning.

Answer (score 39):

All fields in a class extending StatelessWidget should be final.

From the documentations.

> StatelessWidget class. A widget that does not require mutable state.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html

Comment: I am getting the same warning for StatefulWidget.

Comment: @ASADHAMEED  non final variables can be in state class of your stateful widget not in widget class. Widget class must have final variables.

Answer (score 14):

Make sure that all your instances variable in class are marked as final and the object is also marked as final.

In class

```
class Items {
  final String title;
  final String author;
  final String event;
  final String img;
  Items({this.title, this.author, this.event, this.img});
}
```

Inside widget that you in,

```
 final Items item2 = new Items(
    title: "Country",
    author: "Balaji",
    event: "4 Items",
    img: "assets/panda.png",
  );
```

Comment: What is the relation of `Items` to `Episode3`, of this post to the question?

Answer (score 3):

***Use That way***

```
   class Frog extends StatelessWidget {
      const Frog({
      Key key,
      this.color = const Color(0xFF2DBD3A),
      this.child,
   }) : super(key: key);

  final Color color;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(color: color, child: child);
  }
}
```

Comment: If i need to make a variable final, how can i modify it? ad example i have an int variable that i need do increase or decrease, if it's is final i cannot do it.

Comment: @Kobazzo Then you need another variable. And initial that final value to the new variable. Example- You get int value as final ( final int f)  from other screens. Get a new variable int n; Create a initstate() methord and initial  the final value f to n by using setstate()

Comment: @Abir Ahsan but that would throw an ext.flutter.inspector.getRootWidgetSummaryTree Error??

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will be helpful to someone else:

I am new to Flutter and I ran into this issue recently. I couldn't set my variables as `final`, though, because I needed to be able to change the values of the variables. I found out that in my case I needed to use a [`StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) instead of a `StatelessWidget`.

Comment: unless you need the state in the stateful widget there is no need to declare that widget as stateful, just use the linter ignore comment and you're good.

Answer (score 2):

From flutter doc:

> The following is a skeleton of a stateless widget subclass called GreenFrog.
>   Normally, widgets have more constructor arguments, each of which corresponds to a final property.

Just like this

```
class IconContainer extends StatelessWidget {
final double size;
final Color color;
final IconData icon;
IconContainer(this.icon, {this.color=Colors.white, this.size=32});
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 //TODO...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Any an immutable class add after it "final" to next line of flutter code, this will solve your problem,

For example:-

```
class Register extends statelesswidget { 
static const string idScreen = 'register'; 
final TextEditingController name  = TextEditingController();
final TextEditingController email = TextEditingController();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In case that it is possible you can make your field static. This will also solve your issue.

A static field is independent of any class. As long as you don't try to pass it in the constructor and it is not private, it should be fine. If you must have a private field then, you can go with the accepted answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this line top of the warning:

```
//ignore: must_be_immutable
```

Comment: This is not the solution.

Comment: @Arijeet If it compile with the warning, why have a warning in the first place? It's obvious that there are a lot of cases that class-members change during executing... Bad design of a programming language.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you cannot make the class immutable with out making all its properties 'final'. Sometimes we have to make a property not required and have to remove final. In this case your class never be immutable. You can simply ignore the warning. this will not harm your performance.

Answer (score 0):

If the class you design requires a member that can change values after it construct (in build() or other method) for best practice design, I suggest using StatefulWidget instead. Because StatelessWidget has designed for @immutable, it not design for change value of member after create and not support initState() and dispose().

If you still resist and need to using StatelessWidget, you can add ignore to your code

```
// ignore: must_be_immutable
```

or ignore for whole file

```
// ignore_for_file: must_be_immutable
```

and change you class member value in class method(s) without warning,
or use final object to collect value instead. Yeah! no warning but not good design.

```
class IdotCare extends StatelessWidget {
    final Map _myData = {};

    IdotCare({super.key});

    void _todayText() {
        _myData['dynamic_value'] = 'Today is ${DateTime.now()}';
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       _todayText();
       return Text(_myData['dynamic_value']);
    }
}
```

sorry for my bad english.