# Immutable class in flutter?

Tags: class, flutter, immutability

I am getting this->
[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frHUV.png)

What is this immutable class? And how I need to correct this.

Comment: Hey, did you have a look at this ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54707731/this-class-inherits-from-a-class-marked-as-immutable-and-therefore-should-be-i

Comment: If ya ain't satisfied with the link that App Dev sent, give more info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fields in a stateless widget should be marked as final, so change fields to

```
final pinPillPosition
final currentlySelectedPin
```

Do this in your stateless widget or you can ignore the warning by

```
//ignore: must_be_immutable
```