# How to fix class @immutable in flutter?

Tags: flutter

```
class AppForm extends StatefulWidget {

  final String perusahaan;
  final String alamat;

  AppForm ({this.formKey, this.perusahaanController, this.alamatController, this.perusahaan, this.alamat});
  // Required for form validations
  GlobalKey<FormState> formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  // Handles text onchange
  TextEditingController perusahaanController;
  TextEditingController alamatController;
```

The error message:

> "This class "AppForm" (or a class that this class inherits from) is
> marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't
> final: AppForm.formKey, AppForm.perusahaanController,
> AppForm.alamatController"

How to fix that problem?

Comment: As the warning says, you have to declare these fields as `final`: AppForm.formKey, AppForm.perusahaanController, AppForm.alamatController

Comment: this question is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54707731/this-class-inherits-from-a-class-marked-as-immutable-and-therefore-should-be-i

Comment: @AbhishekVishwakarma: Sai Sushmitha extends `StatelessWidget`, the above `StatefulWidget`.